# Can your rebuild a repo with only an IDX and PACK file?

Tags: git

How can a `.idx` and `.pack` files be utilized without the original repository? Can a repository be restored using these files only and if not what else is needed?

Answer (score 2):

From the top of your tree, try running:

```
git index-pack .git/objects/pack/PACK_FILENAME
```

where `PACK_FILENAME` is the name of your pack file. For instance, a repository I tried this on had the path:

```
.git/objects/pack/pack7e0af787b3e455fac722264ff05dd0bae7d71625.pack
```

You should do that for each pack file, and you're repository should be in working order again.

Comment: What if it was in a new empty repo?